# Вывести текст поверх курсора

Tags: javascript

Имеется собственный курсор поверх которого хотелось бы выводить текст. В основном это сумма чисел выбранных пользователем. Это вообще возможно средствами JavaScript?

---

Курсор - это нестандартный указатель мышки. За ним "перемещается" текстовое поле с некоторым смещением.

Всё выводиться и перемещается, но сам курсор перекрывает поле(его видно только при перемещении). Можно ли каким нибудь образом сделать отображение текстового поля поверх курсора мыши.

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите пример вёрстки и кода. Сейчас непонятно, что вы понимаете под курсором и в чём заключается проблема.

Comment: Курсор - это указатель мышки не стандартный. За ним "перемещается" текстовое поле с некоторым смещением.
Всё выводиться и перемещается, но сам курсор перекрывает поле(его видно только при перемещении). Можно ли каким нибудь образом сделать отображение текстового поля поверх курсора мыши.

Comment: Немного странно звучит то, что вы просите. Может вы имеете ввиду подсказки которые плавают над курсором, и двигаются вместе с ним?

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев возможно...

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение на jQuery. Текст исчезает, когда мышка перестаёт двигаться.

```js
var cursorTimer;
var lastX, lastY;

$(document).bind('mousemove', function(e) {
    clearTimeout(cursorTimer);
    
    if(lastX != e.pageX || lastY != e.pageY) {
        lastX = e.pageX;
        lastY = e.pageY;

        $('#cursorText').offset({ left: e.pageX + 5, top: e.pageY - 5 });
        $('#cursorText').css('visibility', 'visible');
    }

    cursorTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        $('#cursorText').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    }, 40);
});
```

```css
#cursorText {
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    cursor: default !important;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cursorText">текст</div>
```

Comment: странно, но у меня даже когда мышка стоит - текст мерцает и движется

Comment: @Grundy А сейчас?

Comment: а сейчас, просто мерацает, то есть показывается и скрывается и т.д.

Comment: что то с реализацией подкачано)

Comment: @ДмитрийШевченко добавь ещё стиль к курсору `default`, вроде будет не плохо смотреться тогда.

Comment: @Grundy исправил.

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример, используем событие `mousemove` и св-ва `pageX`, `pageY`;

```js
var cursorWatcher = document.querySelector('.cursor-watcher');
document.onmousemove = function (e) {
  cursorWatcher.style.left = e.pageX + "px";
  cursorWatcher.style.top = e.pageY + "px";
}
```

```css
.cursor-watcher {
  position: fixed;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 70px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
  <div class='cursor-watcher'>
      Следим за курсором
  </div>
```